# How to show Interstitial ads every 20 seconds in Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, admob, interstitial

How to show Interstitial ads every 20 seconds in Kotlin?

i used this steps to load ad after 20 seconds
i want to load ad every 20 seconds in my app
please 
help

```
    //ads

    // Sample AdMob app ID: ca-app-pub-3940256099942544~3347511713
    MobileAds.initialize(this, "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544~3347511713")
    mAdView = findViewById(R.id.adView)
    val adRequest = AdRequest.Builder().build()
    mAdView.loadAd(adRequest)
    mInterstitialAd = InterstitialAd(this)
    mInterstitialAd.adUnitId = "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/1033173712"
    mInterstitialAd.loadAd(AdRequest.Builder().build())

    val adsHandler = object : Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()){
        override fun handleMessage(msg: Message?) {
            mInterstitialAd.show()
        }
    }

    fun scheduleAd(){
        adsHandler.sendEmptyMessageDelayed(0, 20)
    }
    mInterstitialAd.setAdListener(object : AdListener() {
        override fun onAdLoaded() {
            scheduleAd()
        }

        override fun onAdClosed() {
            // reschedule
            scheduleAd()
        }
    })

    fun loadAd() {
        adsHandler.post {
            mInterstitialAd.loadAd(AdRequest.Builder().build())
            adsHandler.postDelayed(refresh, 20 * 1000) //called every 20 seconds
        }
    }
    //ads over
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
private val refresh = Runnable { loadAd() }

private fun loadAd() {
        adsHandler.post {
            mInterstitialAd.loadAd(AdRequest.Builder().build())
            adsHandler.postDelayed(refresh, 20 * 1000) //called every 20 seconds
        }
}
```

and you can start your timer with `loadAd()`

Comment: I don't have your code in front of me... you have to adapt a little bit on your side

Comment: can you help me please

Comment: how to send to you

Comment: I think he has other problems (other than the initial problem) in your code. It's hard to help you